# Adding a Stagger Effect Entrance Animation to a Heading using Gsap in Elementor

Tags: javascript, css, animation, elementor, gsap

I need some help with animating a heading text in Elementor. Specifically, I want to create an entrance animation where each letter slides in from the bottom one by one, creating a staggered effect. Can you guide me on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

I tried the code below and it worked only when the page loads. How do I get it to work only when a part of the heading text is visible on the users screen?

```
<style>
.char {
    transform: translateY(200px);
    transition: transform .8s ;
}

</style>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.4.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/split-type"></script>

<script>
       const myText = new SplitType('h1')

        gsap.to('.char', {
            y: 0,
            stagger: 0.02,
            delay: 0.5,
            duration: .1,
           
        })
 
</script>
```